# Fouiller profondément

Tags: expressions, synonymes

Quand je parle, par exemple, de ma recherche ou de ma présentation, ou de mon article, et quelqu'un me demande pourquoi je n'avais pas expliqué quelque chose, pourquoi il n'y avait pas assez de détails sur tel ou tel sujet, et je veux dire que je *ne voulais pas aller si loin* (dans mes recherches), que je ne voulais pas expliquer cela en détail, est-il possible d'utiliser cette expression :

> *Je ne voulais pas fouiller si profondément* ?

Sinon, quelles sont les bonnes variantes pour expliquer ce processus de recherche détaillé ? Sauf *aller loin*, que j'ai mentionnée. On peut dire, peut-être, *plonger profondément* (dans le sujet) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quelques formules, et il y en a certainement beaucoup d'autres, selon les situations :

- Indiquer une impossibilité ou une contrainte :

  > - Je n'ai pas voulu (pu) approfondir ce sujet, parce que ...
  > - Je n'ai pas poursuivi mes investigations (mes recherches) dans ce sens, parce que ...
  > - Ce point (ce sujet) ne fait pas partie de mon périmètre de recherche.
- Laisser entendre que l'on connaît la réponse, ou la donner après l'exposé :

  > - Je n'ai pas détaillé ce paragraphe (ce point [particulier]) parce que ..
  > - J'ai délibérément omis d'en parler parce que, ...
- S'appuyer sur la clarté du discours :

  > - Il aurait fallu aussi détailler tels autres points qui devraient être déjà connus de tous.
  > - Je ne l'ai pas développé pour ne pas alourdir la présentation, mais je peux vous répondre maintenant.

Comment: Pour améliorer la réponse, on pourrait séparer les phrases qui indiquent une recherche (délibérément) incomplète (propositions 1, 3 et 5) et celles qui indiquent un choix de non présentation malgré que les connaissances soient là (toutes les autres propositions)

Answer (score 2):

*Aller dans autant de détails* est une expression qui me vient spontanément à l'esprit. Je sais qu'on emploie plus généralement *creuser* et non *fouiller* dans ce sens (*fouiller* implique que c'est la difficulté pratique des recherches trop longues et minutieuses qui cause problème plutôt que le risque de passer hors sujet), mais je suis pas certain des collocations usuelles avec *creuser*.

Comment: +1 Moi je creuse, et parfois je creuse en profondeur et des fois j'aurais bien aimé avoir eu le temps de creuser encore plus profond.

Answer (score 1):

J'aime utiliser le type de phrase suivant pour parler d'un sujet que je n'ai pas "fouillé profondément" (comme vous dites) :

> Je n'ai pas poussé mes recherches/explications pour éviter les
>   incompréhensions dues à une trop grande quantité de
>   détails/d'informations.

Comme je n'ai pas assez de réputation, je répondrais ici @Circeus , veuillez m'excuser :

On utilise *creuser* de votre contexte ainsi, par exemple : Je ne voulais pas creuser dans ce sens / creuser le sujet

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is

> je ne suis pas entré dans les détails

or in a more researched way :

> je ne suis pas entré suffisamment dans les détails